# module.exports inline function variables not defined

Tags: javascript, module, inline

My little project and learning javascript is moving on nicely (in a big part thanks to the folks on here)

I am struggling with module.exports. I believe the issue is because the variables I am trying to get at are buried in the inline function in here:

```
var login = require('./myAirLogin')
var http = require('http');
var parseString = require ('xml2js').parseString;
var options = {
   hostname: '192.168.1.200',
   port: 80,
   path: '/getSystemData',
   method: 'GET'
};

//Get the system variables from MyAir

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {

    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (systemdata) {
parseString(systemdata,{explicitArray:false,trim:true,ignoreAttrs:true},//childkey:9},//explicitArray:false},//explicitChildren:false}, 
            function (err, sysdata) {
           var myairActualTemp= Number(sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.centralActualTemp);
           var myairAirconOnOff= (sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.airconOnOff);
           var myairFanSpeed= Number(sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.fanSpeed);
           var myairMode= (sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.mode);
           var myairDesiredTemp= Number(sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.centralDesiredTemp);
           var myairNumberOfZones= Number(sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.numberOfZones);
           var myairMaxUserTemp= Number(sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.maxUserTemp);
           var myairMinUserTemp= Number(sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.minUserTemp);
           var myairErrorCode= (sysdata["iZS10.3"].system.unitcontrol.airConErrorCode);
       });
    });

});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});
req.end();
```

If i introduce a variable i.e

```
module.exports.zones=8;
```

In the initial block I can access them from external files.

```
var sysdata=require('./myAirGetSysData');
console.log(sysdata.myairNumberOfZones)
console.log(sysdata.zones)
```

However the myairNumberOfZones cannot be called. 
I have tried wrapping the systemdata and systems functions with an export at various points and using all the syntax I can find in here but am obviously missing something.

Comment: And are you exporting `myairNumberOfZones`? Or your problem is how to export something that is executed inside that function? Unless you explicitly export it, you will not be able to access it from the outside.

Comment: I have been trying. I can't find the correct syntax/placement to make it available.

Answer (score 0):

You can put module.exports = {
    getZones: getZones
};

Make a getter function for zones